# Implement a REST service with Extbase (Typo3)

Tags: rest, service, typo3, extbase, typo3-flow

I'm searching for a way to implement a `REST-Service` in an `extbase extension` for `Typo3`.
I've only found old or not maintained extensions and they doesn't use `extbase`.

So how could I get an extension that provides an API for external requests?
Something like:

```
GET www.somedoma.in/service/item/1
```

I've found this tutorial for [Typo3 Flow](http://www.networkteam.com/blog/post/soap-webservices-mit-typo3-flow.html). So how could I use Flow packages in extbase?

I've also found a way to define own page types like `?type=23123145` where the respond can be manipulated. But i think that's no good idea to implement a `REST-Service extension`.

Answer (score 3):

I started to create an extension, because I was interested in this topic.
The current state can be found under  https://github.com/cundd/rest. It requires cundd_composer to be installed and is a work in process ;-)

Update 1:
Ad:  ;-)
the extension is used in production and is under continuing development. To name some of the features:
- Support for Extbase
- Mapping of tables
- Authentication

Update 2:
The project website is live: http://rest.cundd.net

Answer (score 2):

You can't use FLOW3 packages in TYPO3.

AFAIK, TYPO3 hasn't native REST support yet and it can be tricky to use RESTful methods such as PUT or DELETE. However you can with common Extbase ext and RealURL create an API, which will be able to send responses for GET or POST requests.

BTW if the only target of your implementation is to create RESTful API I'd suggest to use some lightweight framework on top of it. Main purpose of the TYPO3 is to deliver universal and comfortable CMS system, but its performance sometimes can not compared to dedicated solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the symfony 2 serializer component! I use it as standalone version as lib. Here is a [tutorial](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/01/the-symfony2-serializer-component-create-a-normalizer-for-json-class-hinting/)